# What is the Efficiency and Performance of LINQ and Lambda Expression in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5, lambda

I have used .Net 3.5 and VS 2008 for more than a month. Like most .Net developers, I have evolved from years experience in .Net 1.0 & 2.0 and VS 2005. Just recently, I discovered the simplicity and power of LINQ and Lambda Expressions, as in my recent questions such as [Find an item in list by LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175645/find-an-item-in-list-by-linq), [Convert or map a class instance to a list of another one by using Lambda or LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176038/convert-or-map-a-class-instance-to-a-list-of-another-one-by-using-lambda-or-linq), and [Convert or map a list of class to another list of class by using Lambda or LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178891/convert-or-map-a-list-of-class-to-another-list-of-class-by-using-lambda-or-linq).

I admit that Lambda and LINQ are much simpler and easy to read and they seem very powerful. Behind the scenes, the .Net compiler must generate lots of code to achieve those functions.  Therefore I am little bit hesitant to switch to the new syntax since I already know the "old" way to achieve the same results.

My question is the about the efficiency and performance of Lambda and LINQ. Maybe Lambda expressions are mostly in-line functions, in that case I guess Lambda should be okay. How about LINQ?

Let's limit the discussion to LINQ-to-Objects LINQ-to-SQL (LINQ-to-SQL). Any comments, comparison and experiences?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's no one single answer that will suffice here.

LINQ has many uses, and many implementations, and thus many implications to the efficiency of your code.

As with every piece of technology at our fingertips, LINQ can and will be abused and misused alike, and the ability to distinguish between that, and proper usage, is only dependent on one thing: knowledge.

So the best advice I can give you is to go and read up on how LINQ is really implemented.

Things you should check into are:

- LINQ and how it uses the methods and extension methods on existing collection types

  - [How LINQ Works](http://aabs.wordpress.com/2006/12/15/how-linq-works-%E2%80%93-creating-queries/)
  - [How LINQ works internally (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671235/how-linq-works-internally)
  - [How does coding with LINQ work? What happens behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835569/how-does-coding-with-linq-work-what-happens-behind-the-scenes)
- How LINQ-to-objects and LINQ-to-SQL differs

  - [What is the difference between LINQ query expressions and extension methods (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796246/what-is-the-difference-between-linq-query-expressions-and-extension-methods)
- Alternatives to the new LINQ syntax, for instance, the usage of the .Where(...) extension method for collections

And as always, when looking at efficiency questions, the only safe approach is just to measure. Create a piece of code using LINQ that does a single, know, thing, and create an alternative, then measure both, and try to improve. Guessing and assuming will only lead to bad results.

Answer (score 6):

Technically the fastest way is to control all the minutia yourself.  [Here are some performance tests](http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html).  Notice that the foreach keyword and the ForEach LINQ construct are identically far far slower than just using for and writing procedural code.

However, the compiler can and will be improved and you can always profile your code and optimize any problematic areas.  It is generally recommended to use the more expressive features that make code easier to read unless you really need the extra nanoseconds.

Comment: That example is really not a good test. Firstly, he's comparing a single reverse iteration + delete to double iteration + list creation + delete. Secondly, why delete when you can instead *select the values you want*? This method, using LINQ is even faster than reverse-for + delete. Thirdly, he's not taking JIT into account, running my tests twice show that the second time around, the LINQ method is (surprisingly enough) 100x faster. My findings: http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/4408/linq.png

Where "Silly LINQ" is his method of double iteration + creation + delete.

Comment: Follow up: that test was not so much a test of LINQ versus "traditional constructs", as much as it's a test of efficient code vs inefficient code. For example, the List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match) method is multiple times faster than the reverse-iteration + delete method, and certainly a lot prettier than writing this efficient way yourself! So I second your opinion to not use a method based on assumptions about efficiency that prove to be wrong ("elegant constructs are slow") but based on correctness.

Comment: Failing to take into account the cost of the jitting is an extremely common error amongst people who don't have much experience writing realistic benchmarks. The closer to "reality" the scenario is, the better the results will be; benchmarking only the first call to a method is highly unrealistic. In reality, most performance problems are a result of millions of calls, only one of which is the first!

Answer (score 5):

For LINQ queries, with the 'new syntax', the IL (code) generated, is fundamentally no different than calling the extension methods provided by Enumerable and Queryable directly.

Answer (score 3):

Dont optimize prematurely. Use Linq and the new extension methods liberally if they improve readability and profile your application afterwards.

Most times the difference between Linq and using plain for loops is not relevant at all. The improved maintainability of your code should be worth a few ms.
Linq can be slower because it works on enumerators which are implemented as state machines. So plain for(...) loops will be faster.

I would recommend following Lasse V. Karlsens advice and append http://www.davesquared.net/2009/07/enumerables-linq-and-speed.html to his link list.

Answer (score 3):

There is no performance difference between LINQ queries and Lambda expressions.

You should completely understand how LINQ feature(both Lambda, LINQ queries) works in .Net before you are looking into performance issues.

Basically you can work with any one of both LINQ queries and Lambda expressions..

**LINQ Queries**

1. It is high level readable query.
2. It is converted into equalent Lambda
   expressions and Lambda expressions added as nodes into an expression tree. Expression tree 
   which  makes structure of lambda expressions. This is
   done by    compiler.
3. Query provider looks into
   expressions(added as nodes in expression tree) and
   produces equalent SQL query operators thus equalent sql query formed during
   runtime.
4. Return Type : Result set (IEnumerable).

**Lambda Expressions**

1. It is a set of expressions/statements and creates delegate /
   expression tree. It can
   be passed to a function as an
   argument.
2. It supports all the LINQ methods like LINQ queries.
   (Where,Select,Count,Sum,etc)
3. An expression tree formed which
   makes structure of lambda
   expressions. This is done by
   compiler.
4. Query provider looks into
   expressions(expression tree) and
   produces equalent SQL query during
   runtime.
5. Return Type : Delagate /
   Expression Tree

**Which is Best?**

You can understand the LINQ (Queries,Lambda) If you look into the above points.

Advantage of LINQ query - It is readable.

Advantage of Lambda

1. Lambda will have an advantage since it creates a delegate and by using
   the delagte you can just pass the
   input paremeters and get the result
   for the different input
   parameters.You need not write
   different queries for different
   criteria as well.
2. You can create dynamic query by
   using Lambda expressions and
   Expression trees.
3. You can use Lambda expressions if
   you want to pass the result of
   statement(s) to a method as an
   argument.
4. expressions are shorter.

So Lambda expression is the best for development over LINQ queries.

Comment: This post is nonsense. Lambda expressions and LINQ are not alternative methods of doing the same thing. One complements the other. By far the most readable way of doing LINQ is to implement the query delegates in lambda syntax. Expressing 'advantages of LINQ over lambda' is meaningless. They do perform fundamentally different tasks.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases LINQ is just as fast if not faster than other methods, but in other cases it can be slower.  We work on a project that we converted to linq and the data lookup is faster but the merging of data between two tables is much slower.  There is a little overhead, but in most cases I don't see the speed difference having much effect on your program.