# Find multiple indices (indexes) of elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working with a legacy jQuery project and need to get the indices of all columns of a table that have the class `unsorted`.  [jQuery can easily get a single index,](https://api.jquery.com/index/) but I need to get an array of indices.  How can I do this?

For example, this will return a single integer even though there are multiple columns with the `unsorted` class:

```
$('.some-table th').index($('th.unsorted'))
```

##### Other Questions

Although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24241462/241142) mentions jQuery, it is really has nothing to do with jQuery or DOM elements, and therefore doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery does not has that function, it could be

```
const $ths = $('.some-table th');
let indices = $.map($('th.unsorted'), function(element) {
  return $ths.index(element);
});
```

Or you could extend the function by yourself.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  indices: function(selector) {
    return $.map($(selector), function(element) {
      return this.index(element);
    });
  },
});

let indices = $('.some-table th').indices('th.unsorted');
```

Moreover, you could write the search logic by yourself for the performance reason.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your `th.unsorted` are siblings (all in the same `thead`) then you don't need `collection.index(selector)` and can apply `.map()` to the `th.unsorted` list directly.

If they're (eg) on different rows, then use the `collection.index(element)` from the other answer.

```js
console.log($("table th.unsorted").map((i, e) => $(e).index()).toArray())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th class='unsorted'>2</th>
    <th class='unsorted'>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th class='unsorted'>5</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```