# IndexOf() he will only show the first encounter with the letter

Tags: javascript

```
**// function for searching the positions of a letter**
function zoekLetter() {
    var letter = "Minister Jet Bussemaker van Onderwijs, Cultuur en      Wetenschap bracht maandag een bezoek aan SintLucas locatie Boxtel. Vanuit het Koning Willem College waren hierbij aanwezig: Cor van Gerven, Erwin Brouwer en de leerlingen Gezel schilder Rick van Hoof, Wesley Stolzenbach en de Gezel stukadoor Rick van der Werf. Doel van het bezoek van de minister was om de titel Meester, die de excellentie van iemands vakmanschap bestempelt, te bespreken en te kijken of deze binnenhet mbo ingezet kan worden. Bijvoorbeeld bij een 'moderne' opleiding zoals Game art.";
    var letterinvoer = prompt("voer een letter in!");
    for (i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
        var locatie = letter.indexOf(letterinvoer);
        alert(locatie);
    }

}
```

**// it will only show the first encounter with the letter given in the prompt, and i need to show all the positions**

Comment: take a look at the reference -> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: this was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710345/finding-all-indexes-of-a-specified-character-within-a-string