# Locating multiple same sub-strings in a string

Tags: javascript, locate, substring

For example, I have a word such as "Unfortunate" and I need to locate all the "t"s inside the string.

indexOf doesn't work here because it only locates the first sub-string it finds and nor do all the javascript methods I could find

Comment: by locate you mean find index of all t's?

Comment: have a look at regex's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all indexes of a specified character within a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710345/finding-all-indexes-of-a-specified-character-within-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getAllIndexes(string, val) {
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    return indexes;
}

var indexes = getAllIndexes("Unfortunate", "t");
console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: We should not answer very obvious question. Instead, we should check and if possible mark them as duplicate

Comment: @Rajesh I understand.. sorry

Comment: No need for apology mate. Its all good. We fall only to pick ourselves up and in the process we emerge enlightened.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var indexArr = [];
var testSrt = "Unfortunate".split("");
testSrt.forEach(function(element, index) {
   if (element == "t") {
      indexArr.push(index);
   }
});
console.log(indexArr);
```

Comment: We should not answer very obvious question. Instead, we should check and if possible mark them as duplicate