# How to read the position of a word which at multiple times in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, regex

If that is my Text:

```
<textarea readonly id="rightbox" class="rightbox">
From: Emailadress
Sender: Emailadress
Reply-To: Emailadress
</textarea>
```

How can I read the Positions of Emailadress?

I tried it with indexof

```
var str = document.getElementById('rightbox').innerHTML;
var pos = str.indexOf('{Emailadress}');
```

I only get the Position of the 1. Emailadress.
Is it possible to get all positions and write them in an Array?

Comment: `Emailadresse !== Emailadress`

Comment: Also `'leftbox'  !== 'rightbox'` but I think it's just typos in the questions :-)

Comment: It is already answered in the following question. See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40281656/1273550](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40281656/1273550)

Comment: `indexOf` takes a second parameter `fromIndex`, that - you guessed it - allows you to specify from which position to start the search. So you can easily put that into a loop that you keep going as long as it does not return -1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all indexes of a specified character within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710345/finding-all-indexes-of-a-specified-character-within-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change `rightbox` as `id` instead of `leftbox`, second use [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) instead of [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

And [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) will give you the first occurrence of matched string(check `Emailadresse`).

```js
var str = document.getElementById('rightbox').value;
console.log('Position of Emailadress:'+str.indexOf('{Emailadresse}'));
console.log('Position of Emailadress:'+str.indexOf('Emailadress'));
// to get all occurence of Emailaddress
var regexp = /Emailadress/g;
var key, positions = [];
while ((key = regexp.exec(str)) != null) {
  positions.push(key.index);
}

console.log(positions);
```

```html
<textarea readonly id="rightbox" class="rightbox">
From: Emailadress
Sender: Emailadress
Reply-To: Emailadress
</textarea>
```

Comment: I think the question is: how do you get all the positions. But that's very badly worded.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var str = "I learned to play the Ukulele in Lebanen with neel."
 var regex = /ne/gi, result, indices = [];
 while ( (result = regex.exec(str)) ) {
    indices.push(result.index);
 }
Answers:indices= 6,37,46
```