# A string method to return all placements of a specified string?

Tags: javascript, methods

Is there a method like indexOf but that would return all placements of the specified string, in an array? Like `"test test atest".method(test)` would return `[0, 5, 11]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all indexes of a specified character within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710345/finding-all-indexes-of-a-specified-character-within-a-string)

Comment: Some people misuse the `replace` method as follows: `let indices = [];
"test test atest".replace(/test/g, (match, i) => indices.push(i));`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of such a method, but it's pretty easy to write using `indexOf`:

```
function findAll(string, substring) {
    var i = -1;
    var indices = [];

    while ((i = string.indexOf(substring, i+1)) !== -1) {
        indices.push(i);
    }

    return indices;
}

console.log(findAll("test test atest", "test"));

// Output:
// [ 0, 5, 11 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an custom prototype of string with iterating all results of [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```js
String.prototype.getIndicesOf = function (s) {
    var result = [],
        p= this.indexOf(s);
    
    while (p !== -1) {
        result.push(p);
        p = this.indexOf(s, p + 1);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log("test test atest".getIndicesOf("test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question title specifically asks for a string method, and the technique below technically uses a RegExp method (where the string is, instead, a parameter of the method). However, it *is* fairly straightforward:

```js
const regex = /test/g;
const indices = [];
while (result = regex.exec('test test atest')) indices.push(result.index);
console.log(JSON.stringify(indices));
```

It can also easily be converted into a nice, neat call-able function:

```js
const findIndices = (target, query) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(query, 'g');
  const indices = [];
  while (result = regex.exec(target)) indices.push(result.index);
  return indices;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(
  findIndices('test test atest', 'test')
));
```