# Get all occurrences of a substring in a very big string

Tags: javascript

Something like indexOf, except I need to find all indexes. If there's .indexOf and ,lastIndexOf , shouldn't there be a function to get all index occurences? I couldn't find.

Note that the string is very large, about 1MB in size, so I would need the fastest solution.

To clarify, I need to get all positions of where a substring occurs in a string.

E.g.

```
var str = "foo bar foo bar"; //the real string is 1MB
var indexes = str.indexOfAll('foo'); //the function I need
console.log(indexes); //should print [0,8];
```

One thing that comes to mind is to use indexOf in a recurring loop, finds the first word, cut the string at the index, then use indexOf again and so on until it finds nothing. I'm not sure about performance (cutting and re-creating large strings).

Comment: `indexOf` within loop

Comment: Yeah I just thought about that edited my answer. But is there something more optimal?

Comment: I would disagree about this duplicate. It is about searching for a string in an array, but this question is about searching for a string pattern, which can be achieved using string-search algorithms like Knuth-Morris-Pratt or Boyer-Moore.

Comment: _is there something more optimal?_ IMO loop with `indexOf` is most optimal. It doesn't cut/re-create strings. Furthermore, it doesn't make redundant iterations if one uses 2nd parameter of  `indexOf`

Comment: I'm going to try it and see how much it takes. I didn't know you can use indexOf in a loop just like that. If it takes a lot of time I'm going to try that string search algo. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate either, at least of the question that is marked now. And the previous one which is no longer there, was about finding characters in a small string.

Comment: _was about finding characters in a small string._ Size (of both needle and haystack) doesn't matter. `indexOf` work with any strings. Finding a character in a string is just particular case.

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk I think that the basic implement ion of any language for a purpose is fastest. But I reopened the question. Lets see if you get some efficient solution.

Comment: What should happen if the string is `foo bar foo bar food`  should it return [0,8,16]?

Comment: @MaheerAli Yes, it could be the same case. Though if I saw it correct, the top answer operated specifically on characters. Nevermind. Thanks for re-opening. I will update when I implement it.

Comment: It seems that you eventually chose "`indexOf` in loop" solution. So, as I wrote, your post is assumed to be a dupe, as [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710345/finding-all-indexes-of-a-specified-character-within-a-string) has mostly [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10710406/2118955).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy solution:

```
const str = "...";
const searchKeyword = "...";

const startingIndices = [];

let indexOccurence = str.indexOf(searchKeyword, 0);

while(indexOccurence >= 0) {
    startingIndices.push(indexOccurence);

    indexOccurence = str.indexOf(searchKeyword, indexOccurence + 1);
}
```

If you need something highly performant, you may look over specific text search/indexing algorithms like [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) or [Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm).

Really depends on your use case and if the text you're searching into is changing or is static and can be indexed beforehand for maximum performance.

Comment: It worked fine, 1ms. Thanks. I didn't know there was an extra param to indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const IndexString = (str1, str2, output=[]) =>{
  for(let i = 0; i < str1.length -1; i++){
    let arr = [];
    for(let j = i; j < (i+str2.length) & i<str1.length; j++) arr.push(str1[j])
    const findnew = arr.join('');
    if(findnew===str2) output.push(i);
  }
  return output
}

console.log(IndexString("tiktok tok tok tik tok tik", "tik"))
```