# Is there a way to know alle the positions of a certain part of a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to know all the positions of a certain part of a string, so for example, if I have a `let variable = "test"` and I want to know the location of all the "t"s.

I tried using indexOf(), but it does only return the location of the first "t" and stops afterwards.

Is there a way to do this with all "t"s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let x = "test"
let y = []
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
   if (x[i] == "t") y.push(i)
}
console.log(y)
```

Comment: This is virtually identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10710400/6243352), but without all of the detail and benchmark. Why not mark a dupe instead of reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let variable = "test";
for (let i = 0; i < variable.length; i++){
    if (variable[i] === 't'){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```