# LINQ query is slow

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

During application profiling I found that function checking for pattern match is very slow. It is written using LINQ. Simple replacement of this LINQ expression with loop makes really huge difference. What is it? Is LINQ really such a bad thing and works so slow or I misunderstand something?

```
private static bool PatternMatch1(byte[] buffer, int position, string pattern)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (char c in pattern)
    {
        if (buffer[position + i++] != c)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

version 2 with LINQ (suggested by Resharper)

```
private static bool PatternMatch2(byte[] buffer, int position, string pattern)
{
    int i = 0;
    return pattern.All(c => buffer[position + i++] == c);
}
```

version 3 with LINQ

```
private static bool PatternMatch3(byte[] buffer, int position, string pattern)
{
    return !pattern.Where((t, i) => buffer[position + i] != t).Any();
}
```

version 4 using lambda

```
private static bool PatternMatch4(byte[] buffer, int position, string pattern, Func<char, byte, bool> predicate)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (char c in pattern)
    {
        if (predicate(c, buffer[position + i++]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

and here is the usage with large buffer

```
const int SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 50;

byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE - 3; ++i)
{
    if (PatternMatch1(buffer, i, "xxx"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Calling `PatternMatch2` or `PatternMatch3` is phenomenally slow. It takes about 8 seconds for `PatternMatch3` and about 4 seconds for `PatternMatch2`, while calling `PatternMatch1` takes about 0.6. As far as I understand it is the same code and I see no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Resharper's suggestion makes me sad. You should NEVER affect future results in a LINQ query like the `i++` does.

Comment: Agree. Anyway, I was using PatternMatch3. I found resharper suggestion 2 minutes ago while preparing source code for this post :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well let's take the Where operator.

It's implementation is almost(*) like:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> fn)
{
    foreach(T i in input) 
        if (fn(i))
            yield return i;
}
```

This means, for each loop over the IEnumerable an iterator object is created - note that you have SIZE - n of these allocations because you do those many LINQ queries.

Then for each character in the pattern you have:

1. A function call to the enumerator
2. A function call to the predicate

The second is a call to a delegate which costs roughly double the calling cost of a typical virtual call (where in the first version you have no extra calls apart the array deindexing.

If you really want brute performance, you probably want to get as "older-style" code as possible. 
In this case I would even replace that foreach in method 1 with a plain for (at the very least if it does not serve to optimize, it makes it more readable since you are keeping track of the index anyway).

It's also more readable in this case, and it shows that Resharper suggestions are sometimes debatable.

(*) I said almost because it uses a proxy method to check that the input enumerable is not null and throw the exception earlier than the time the collection is enumerated -- it's a small detail which does not invalidate what I wrote before, highlighting here for completeness.

Answer (score 7):

Mark Byers and Marco Mp are right about the extra calls overhead. However, there is another reason here: many object allocations, due to a closure.

The compiler creates a new object on each iteration, storing the current values of `buffer`, `position` and `i` that the predicate can use. Here is a dotTrace snapshot of `PatternMatch2` showing this. `<>c_DisplayClass1` is the compiler-generated class.

(Note that the numbers are huge because I'm using tracing profiling, which adds overhead. However, it's the same overhead per call, so the overall percentages are correct).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that the LINQ version has extra function calls. Internally in LINQ your lambda function is called in a loop.

While the extra call *might* be optimized away by the [JIT compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), it's not guaranteed and it can add a small overhead. In most cases the extra overhead won't matter, but because your function is very simple and is called an extremely large number of times, even a small overhead can quickly add up. In my experience LINQ code generally is a little bit slower than equivalent `for` loops. That's the performance price you often pay for a more high level syntax.

In this situation, I would recommend sticking with the explicit loop.

While you're optimizing this section of code, you might also want to consider a more efficient searching algorithm. Your algorithm is worst case O(n*m) but [better algorithms exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Comment: I added version 4 which uses lambda as well. It still takes less than 1 second.

Comment: @Mark Byers: He probably answers my question on the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ's main goal when applied to collections is its simplicity. If you want performance, you should avoid LINQ entirely. Also to enumerate an array you just increment an index variable, while LINQ needs to set up an entire enumerator object.

Comment: Foreach uses enumerator as well. I specially replaced for with foreach in the first version in order to compare.

Comment: "If you want performance". LINQ is often fast enough, even in performance critical path of the application. However, the use case of the code of the OP is an edge case.

Comment: @axe: Actually it doesn't, at least not for arrays: `foreach (type var in array) {...}` is compiled as `for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) { type var = array[i]; ... }` - you can check that with e.g. ILSpy.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried to replace `char pattern` with `IEnumerable<char>`. It became slower (about 2 seconds, but still not 8).