# Comparison : LINQ vs LAMBDA Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need a discussion regarding the Performance of LINQ and Lambda Expression.

Which one is better?

Comment: You might want to look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182922/what-is-the-efficiency-and-performance-of-linq-and-lambda-expression-in-net

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I guess you mean `query expression` when talking about LINQ here.

They are equivalent. The compiler changes the `query expression` into the equivalent Lambda expression before compiling it, so the generated IL is exactly the same.

**Example**

```
var result = select s from intarray
             where s < 5
             select s + 1;
```

is exactly the same as

```
var result = intarray.Where( s => s < 5).Select( s => s+1);
```

Note that if you write the query expression like this:

```
var result = select s from intarray
             where s < 5
             select s;
```

It's converted to:

```
var result = intarray.Where( s => s < 5);
```

The final call to Select is omitted because it's redundant.

Comment: I would have thought the same, but, according to this site ( http://blog.thijssen.ch/2009/02/linq-vs-lambda-vs-loop-performance-test.html ), the Lambda expressions perform faster.
I have copied the Test function into an app, to test it, and it verified the findings on that site.

Comment: Would this mean to learn Lambda expressions only?

Comment: 'query expression' is more readable especially for new ppl

Comment: @Omkar - I actually find the chained lambdas much more readable ;)

Comment: The test at the blog is totally wrong! first of all both of them LINQ one is query expression the other one is Lambda expression form. second just move the LAMBDA part upper than LINQ and re-run the test to see the result!  then remove the int from the query (forces casting cost) then use the intlist in both (not array in one an List in the other one) the result will be the same because compiler translates them to the same thing as the above answer explained nicely. I use both of them: Lambda for simple expressions and query for more complex ones.

Comment: The major difference comes when joins are involved - pretty trivial in query expressions, kind of monstrous when using the manual method calls.

Answer (score 6):

a quick comparison in reflector would probably do the trick. However, from a 'preference' standpoint, I find lambda statements easier to follow and write and use them across the board whether it be with objects, xml or whatever.

If performance is negligible, i'd go with the one that works best for you.

i actually started off a little topic looking at linq methods which may be of interest:

[What's your favourite linq method or 'trick'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466536/whats-your-favourite-linq-method-or-trick)

cheers..