# How to easily validate if an input string is valid lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

For example:

```
Validate("items.Select(item => item.ToLower())")
```

will return True, while

```
Validate("var n=5;")
```

will return False.

The context is that I want to create an application that allows users to manipulate their data via a lambda expression. If the user inputs a valid lambda expression, the program will execute it. Otherwise, it should fail.

Comment: What's the context?  How will this be used?  Why does it need to be a string version of the LINQ expression and not the LINQ expression?  Just trying to arrive at the intent so I can better understand a solution.

Comment: what if you have a LINQ expression that throws an exception, what should your method return for that? Is it a valid LINQ expression? This seems to me more like an unsolvable problem.

Comment: FYI that's not a "Linq" expression, it's a Lamba expression.

Comment: Without some real context this problem is not solvable IMHO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a string C# LINQ expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782538/parsing-a-string-c-sharp-linq-expression)

Comment: @asawyer, I think they are equivalent (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914611/comparision-linq-vs-lambda-expression)

Comment: @zer0ne These are Lambda expressions in a LINQ context. By no means are they restricted to LINQ queries however.

Comment: LINQ are extension methods. Lambda are compiler sugar for anonymous methods. You can use Lambda with LINQ methods, or you can use query expressions.

Comment: @asawyer Changed to Lambda expression

Comment: @AdiLester Sure, I'll delete this question in a bit.

Comment: @zer0ne Don't delete it, let it close as duplicate or remain open.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend of keeping it simple and just trying to execute it.
If it isnt valid, it will fail anyway a few milliseconds later.

It also deals with expressions that are syntactically valid, but fail from a different reason.

If you choose to take this approach, than it only takes to use the Dynamic Linq library and you are done.

Comment: "it will fail anyway a few milliseconds later" `LINQValidate("while(true){var s=\"good luck\"";}");`

Comment: If he must deal with evil users, he can execute it on a separate thread and kill it if it takes too long.

Comment: Ok. `LINQValidate("System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(\"cmd format c:\");");`