# LINQ - Does the Where expression return new instance or reference to object instance

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is probably a basic question for some, but it affects how I design a piece of my program.

I have a single collection of type A:

```
IEnumerable<A> myCollection;
```

I am filtering my collection on 2 different criteria:

```
IEnumerable<A> subCollection1 = myCollection.Where(x => x.Count > 10);
etc.
```

Now, I know that the .Where expression will return a new instance of IEnumerable, but does the new collection contain the same reference to an instance of type A that 'myCollection' references, or are new copies of type A created? If new instances of type 'A' are created, is there a way to say that 'subCollection1' references the same instances of A as 'myCollection' references?

Edit: To Add further clarification.

I am looking for a way so that when I make a change to an instance of 'A' in 'subCollection1', that it is also modified for 'myCollection'.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The instances are the same if they are classes, but copies if they are structs/value types.

int, byte and double are [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), as are structs (like `System.Drawing.Point` and self-defined structs).
But strings, all of your own classes, basically "the rest", are [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).

Note: LINQ uses the same rules as all other assignments.

For objects:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.Name = "Mr Jones";
Person p2 = p1;
p2.Name = "Mr Anderssen";
// Now p1.Name is also "Mr Anderssen"
```

For structs:

```
Point p1 = new Point();
p1.x = 5;
Point p2 = p1;
p2.x = 10;
// p1.x is still 5
```

The same rules apply when using LINQ.

Comment: That is what I had presumed. I just wanted to make sure that the Where expression was not doing some sort of shallow copying on my class instances.

Comment: Worth noting that anonymous types are always classes, so references as well.

Comment: @Richard: Also worth noting that anonymous types are immutable in C# so you can't modify an anonymous type instance anyway.

Comment: Is this answer precise? Like romanlv and Andrey said, some linq methods do return a new collection instead of the reference.

Answer (score 18):

Actually it depends on the collection. In some cases, LINQ methods can return cloned objects instead of references to originals. Take a look at this test:

```
[Test]
public void Test_weird_linq()
{
    var names = new[]{ "Fred", "Roman" };
    var list = names.Select(x => new MyClass() { Name = x });

    list.First().Name = "Craig";
    Assert.AreEqual("Craig", list.First().Name);            
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This test will fail, even though many people believe that the same object will be returned by `list.First()`. It will work if you use another collection "modified with `ToList()`".

```
var list = names.Select(x => new MyClass() { Name = x }).ToList();
```

I don't know for sure why it works this way, but it's something to have in mind when you write your code :)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671235/how-linq-works-internally) can help you understand how LINQ works internally.

Comment: Since this is an enumeration the select is actually performed when the list is iterated, so each time you iterate over the list the select will be performed and a new object will be created.

Answer (score 14):

They are same objects. `Where` only filters, `Select` produces (can produce) new instances.

Answer (score 5):

Making a new object that is a reference type is non-trivial. LINQ would have no idea how to do it. LINQ always returns the same instances when dealing with reference types.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add to some of the other answers -- in general, when I'm not sure of something but require a particular behavior, I'll add a unit test for it.  You could easily put this into a test and then check for equality, which will tell you if you're looking at a reference of the object in the original container.  Some may argue that this is stupid because you "should just know" what happens, but for me I know I will either be 1) unsure because I'm not an awesome programmer, and 2) there are always nights where I have to burn the midnight oil, and it's good to have the reassurance that something behaves as you need it to.

Comment: This question stemmed because when I had a collection that I was filtering using the Where expression, my Entity Framework Self Tracking Entities were not behaving correctly. I believe the problem is not due to my misunderstanding of how C# handles references, but a problem with tracking being turned off after performing the Where expression.