# Does LINQ iterate behind the scenes?

Tags: .net, linq

Not the most important question in the world but as a soon graduate I figured I would like to have this knowledge going forward. Having said that, how does LINQ find the data I need based on the conditions I provide behind the scenes?

Consider:

```
String[] straAr = {"Jordan","Jansyn","Corey","Josh","Whitney"};

var sel = from S in straAr
    where S.Contains("syn")
    select S;
```

This will, of course, result in "Jansyn". Before I was introduced to LINQ, I would have done this:

```
String[] straAr = {"Jordan","Jansyn","Corey","Josh","Whitney"};

foreach(String s in straAr)
{
    if(s.Contains("syn"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

They both work, though I think LINQs implementation is much more elegant. Can anyone tell me:

- **How does LINQ query a data structure behind the scenes? Foreach?**
- **Is one implementation more efficient than the other?**

As always, thanks for any input!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671235/how-linq-works-internally

Comment: They're not the same implementation. One writes the results out to console, and the other does nothing. With LINQ the foreach matters.

Comment: No Linq not use foreach statement.If it use foreach statement it lost his LAZY Behaviour.inspite of forEach it use YIELD Statement in  Linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to learn about LINQ internals is by actually looking at the code. Well, you will not be able to look at the original code, but [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) is really a great re-implementation of its full functionality for educational purposes.

To answer at least a part of your questions directly:

- No LINQ typically doesn't use foreach internally. Most of the time, [enumerators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.ienumerator%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are used directly because this allows for a finer control of what's going on
- In general, the second implementation will be more efficient because LINQ offers some additional features (such as laziness) which complicate the generated code a bit. However, this is hardly ever relevant in practice.

Comment: You can look at the original code. I cloned the .NET 5 repo containing Linq, debugged it myself, and wrote an article about how it works behind the scenes:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/linq-behind-the-scenes-efd664d9ebf8?sk=cba7416407ec8b753d9961fe23aac173