# "Method cannot be translated into a store expression" weird behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these two models with one-many relation:

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Times = new HashSet<Time>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Time> Times { get; set; }
}

[Table("Time")]
public class Time
{
    [Key]
    public long TimeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime WorkDay { get; set; }
    public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And method in context class which returns DataTable.
First implementation fails after query goes through .ToDataTable() extension (or .ToList() or whatever)
with exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

Second one goes perfectly fine.
Question is why?

First implementation. It doesn't work

```
public DataTable GetDtProjectsForUser(User user)
{
    var query = from time in Time
                select new
                {
                    WorkDay = time.WorkDay.ToShortDateString(),
                };
    return query.ToDataTable();
}
```

Second one. It DOES work

```
public DataTable GetDtProjectsForUser(User user)
{
    var localUser = User.Find(user.Guid);
    var query = from time in localUser.Times
                select new
                {
                    WorkDay = time.WorkDay.ToShortDateString(),
                };
    return query.ToDataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rohit's answer is more or less correct, but his explanation in comments is wrong.

`localUser.Times` is (presumably) an `ICollection<Time>`. Building an `ICollection` requires enumerating the result set. The query is executed as soon as the collection is referenced. Your query is equivalent to:

```
var collection = localUser.Times.Select(t => new { WorkDay = t.WorkDay.ToShortDateString() });
```

As soon as `localUser.Times` is executed, a query is made to the database and the `Times` collection is loaded. The subsequent `.Select()` is a LINQ to Objects query.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is a deferred execution. In you first code, Time variable is not stored in the memory, while in second code, you have stored the collection in `localUser` variable. 

You can read more about the linq and deferred execution at [Charlie Calvert's Community Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, I know about deferred execution. But in both cases "query" executes when I call ToDataTable extension (at least I think so).

Comment: @Szer, yeah. that is what deferred means to. both queries executes at the time when you call ToDataTable method. But linq execution is not like a normal execution. To better understand about the linq, also prefer [How does LINQ works internally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671235/how-linq-works-internally)